# More generic version of `Variables`

Tags: programming

What's the best way to extend `Variables` to work on expressions that are not polynomial?

IE, the following returns `{x,y}`, but I want `{x,y,z}`

```
expr=2 x + 5 y + 10^z;
Variables[expr]
```

This would be useful for automatically turning expressions into callable functions like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280558/turning-exprreplacement-rules-into-a-function-which-automatically-applies-repla), ie automatically fill variable slots from parameters:

```
makeFunc[expr][1,2,3]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) Also: [Get all variables in an expression with Variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61131/get-all-variables-in-an-expression-with-variables)

Comment: see also [how-to-find-all-symbols-in-an-expression-and-perform-an-operation-on-them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51919/how-to-find-all-symbols-in-an-expression-and-perform-an-operation-on-them)  `Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]]` gives `{x, y, z}`  You can also do `Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity]` which gives `{z, x, y}`